# Fetching data to HTML dropdown list to from database

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I need to fetch user's company type to dropdown list from database. According to my coding data is not fetching properly.I tried to print the result but even it's not outputting anything. Database variable name is 'type'. Could someone give any help?

```
<select name="type" class="form-control">
              <?php


mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '123');
mysql_select_db('db1');

$sql= "SELECT type FROM users";
$result= mysql_query($sql);
echo "$result";

    while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      echo "<option value='". $row['type'] ."'>" .$row['type'] ."</option>" ;
    }


?>

 </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I use on my forms (modified for your terms).

```
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '123');
    mysql_select_db('db1');
    $sql = "SELECT type FROM users";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error in query: $sql. " . mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
       while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
          echo "<option value=\"".$row->type."\">".$row->type."</option>";}}
  }
```

Comment: Did you test this code? It's not working either. The dropdown list is empty. @Michael Moxley

Comment: It should work, it's copy / pasted from a working form of mine.  I know this is simple, but is the table and SQL correct?

Comment: Yeah I just double checked the database names and the table. No idea what's wrong @Michael Moxley  -_-